# can we remove comma (,) from date format in view using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[date format in view ]

`date="December 12, 2015"` in view file, but I want this type format of date   `"December 12 2015"`
I want to remove comma from date view format:

```
 $date = "12,12,2015";
 echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Try this: [func_string_str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this**

```
echo date("F d Y",$date);
```

Comment: i try this and this work fine ,thank you Jawahar Sharma